# JavaScript Routes with Default Values

Tags: javascript, url-routing

Are there any JavaScript Routing libraries that support Default Values for Route parameters?
Here's an example of what I'm after

```
route = /example/{pagenumber}/{pagesize}

defaults = { pagenumber: 0, pagesize: 0}
```

This should match all of the following routes and provide the values shown

1. **/example/** matched with values **{ pagenumber: 0, pagesize: 0}**
2. **/example/1/** matched with values **{ pagenumber: 1, pagesize: 0}**
3. **/example/1/5** matched with values **{ pagenumber: 1, pagesize: 5}**

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know any libraries with default parameters, but what you can do is set default values in the handler function that is called when the route is matched.

Let’s assume `handlerFunc` is registered with the router to handle the route `/example/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}`, and furthermore that the router allows named parameters in routes, and is smart enough to match the following URLs:

1. `/example`
2. `/example/1`
3. `/example/1/5`

Your handler function could then do something like this:

```
function handlerFunc(params) {
    // If URL params were set, use them, otherwise use default value 0.
    var pageNumber = params.byName("pageNumber") || 0;
    var pageSize = params.byName("pageSize") || 0;

    // The rest of your code here ...
}
```

This code assumes `params` is passed to `handlerFunc` and has a method called `byName` that returns the value of the named parameter. If params is a simple array, you could access its values with `params[0]` and `params[1]`.